# How to use javascript string interpolation with Jinja template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I have a jQuery code of datatable. I am trying to insert a button in the last column.

```
columnDef: targets[-1], render :function (data,type, row,meta) {return `{{${edit_button(row.id)}}}`}
```

edit_button is a macro that consist code for a button element.

This code is throwing error $ is undefined.

Kindly give me a way to render Jinja template from jQuery datatable.

Comment: `$ is undefined` normally means that you have no included jquery in your project

Comment: $ is showing error in Jinja not in jquery. That $ is a part of string interpolation `${value}`

Comment: You cannot use server side Jinja macros after the rendered template has been sent to the browser. You have to implement `edit_button` macro is javascript or include the buttons' rendered HTML into the data you sent to the jQuery datatable.